# GLSL Weird Error When Compiling Shader (structs)

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

I have a fragment shader, it has structs and a uniform of those structs. When I tried to compile them, OpenGL gave me this error:

```
0(30) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting '{' at token "lights_a"
0(31) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting '{' at token "material"
```

I don't know what the problem is here. I have been searching for the problem... I looked at line 30 and 31, I did everything I could imagine, but without success.

Here is the code:

```
#version 330 core
struct LightBase
{
    int renderit;

    vec4 ambient_light;
    vec4 specular_light;
    vec4 diffuse_light;

    float radius;

    vec3 light_position;
    vec3 light_direction;

    int light_type;
};

struct MaterialBase
{
    vec4 ambient_affect;
    vec4 specular_affect;
    vec4 diffuse_affect;
    float shining;

    float mirror;

    int light_affect;
};

in vec3 VertexPos;
in vec3 Normal;
uniform int light_quantity;
uniform LightBase lights_a[50];
uniform MaterialBase material;
uniform float usingTex;
uniform sampler2D texturemap;
in vec2 UVs;
in vec4 Colors;
out vec4 color;

void main() {

    vec4 texture_u = texture(texturemap,UVs).rgba * usingTex;
    vec4 color_u = Colors * (1.0f-usingTex);

    vec4 final_color = color_u+texture_u;
    // Light
    for(int i=0;i<light_quantity;i++) {
        if(lights_a[i].renderit==1) {
            if(lights_a[i].light_type==1) {

                float attenuation = max(0.0,1.0-dot(lights_a[i].light_direction,lights_a[i].light_direction));

                vec3 L = normalize(lights_a[i].light_direction);
                vec3 N = normalize(Normal);
                vec3 V = normalize(-VertexPos);
                vec3 R = normalize(-reflect(L,N));

                float nDotL = max(0.0,dot(N,L));
                float rDotV = max(0.0,dot(R,V));

                float ambient_result = lights_a[i].ambient_light * material.ambient_affect * attenuation;
                float diffuse_result = lights_a[i].diffuse_light * material.diffuse_affect * nDotL * attenuation;
                float specular_result = lights_a[i].specular_light * material.specular_affect * pow(rDotV,material.shining) * attenuation;

                vec4 this_colour = (ambient_result + diffuse_result + specular_result) * final_color;
                    final_color = this_colour;
            }
    }
    }


    color = final_color;
}
```

What's wrong about the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see an error when I compile your code -- only a couple of warnings:

```
0(62) : error C7011: implicit cast from "vec4" to "float"
0(63) : error C7011: implicit cast from "vec4" to "float"
0(64) : error C7011: implicit cast from "vec4" to "float"
```

I can almost reproduce the error you see by commenting out the declarations of `struct LightBase` and `struct MaterialBase` -- except they show up on lines 33 and 34. which are the lines with the noted tokens `lights_a` and `material`

This leads me to believe that your problem is that you're not actually compiling the program you think you are.  Perhaps you're reading it from a file into memory, but the memory gets corrupted somehow before you call glShaderSource...

Comment: I'll check the data located in the memory (it's a const char*).

Comment: The data is fine, and the structs are not commented.... This should not be happening, this is weird...

Comment: Yes, I found the error... Actually the data was damaged... It seems right, but it wasn't.